# How to generate an observable from a starting observable, when I can only generate other observables?

Tags: c#, stack-overflow, system.reactive

I want to generate an observable where each value of the observable is dependent on the one before it, starting from a single value. If I have a simple transformation between values like `Func<int, int>`, it is easy to do with `Observable.Generate` like so:

```
Func<int, IObservable<int>> mkInts = init =>
    Observable.Generate(
        init,         // start value
        _ => true,    // continue ?
        i => i + 1,   // transformation function
        i => i);      // result selector

using (mkInts(1).Subscribe(Console.WriteLine))
{
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

This will happily write numbers on my screen until I press enter. However, my transformation function does some network IO, so the type is `Func<int, IObservable<int>>`, so I cannot use that approach. Instead, I have tried this:

```
// simulate my transformation function
Func<int, IObservable<int>> mkInt = ts =>
    Observable.Return(ts)
              .Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10));

// pre-assign my generator function, since the function calls itself recursively
Func<int, IObservable<int>> mkInts = null;

// my generator function
mkInts = init =>
{
    var ints = mkInt(init); 

    // here is where I depend on the previous value.
    var nextInts = ints.SelectMany(i => mkInts(i + 1)); 
    return ints.Concat(nextInts);
};

using (mkInts(1).Subscribe(Console.WriteLine))
{
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

But this will stackoverflow after printing about 5000 numbers. How can I solve this?

Comment: Sounds like you probably want to use a robust storage type like a bag, linked list, or hash table and when things change you add values or mutate values in the storage type instead of creating more and more overall observers.

Comment: @Boris - It looks like you're recursively subscribing to mkInts. Should ints.SelectMany(i => mkInts(i + 1)); actually be ints.SelectMany(i => mkInt(i + 1));? as in mkInt not mkInts?

Comment: @James Hay: If I did that, then my observable would only contain 2 values. I mean for it to contain an infinite amount, like the simpler version I described first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I've got a nice clean solution for you.

First-up, go back to using a `Func<int, int>` - it can easily be turned into a `Func<int, IObservable<int>>` using `Observable.FromAsyncPattern`.

I used this for testing:

```
Func<int, int> mkInt = ts =>
{
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    return ts + 1;
};
```

Now here's the money maker:

```
Func<int, Func<int, int>, IObservable<int>> mkInts = (i0, fn) =>
    Observable.Create<int>(o =>
    {
        var ofn = Observable
            .FromAsyncPattern<int, int>(
                fn.BeginInvoke,
                fn.EndInvoke);

        var s = new Subject<int>();

        var q = s.Select(x => ofn(x)).Switch();

        var r = new CompositeDisposable(new IDisposable[]
        {
            q.Subscribe(s),
            s.Subscribe(o),
        });

        s.OnNext(i0);

        return r;
    });
```

The iterating function is turned into an asynchronous observable.

The `q` variable feeds the values from the subject into the observable iterating function and selects the calculated observable. The `Switch` method flattens out the result and ensures that each call to the observable iterating function is properly cleaned up.

Also, the use of a `CompositeDisposable` allows the two subscriptions to be disposed of as one. Very neat!

It's easily used like this:

```
using (mkInts(7, mkInt).Subscribe(Console.WriteLine))
{
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Now you have a fully parametrized version of your generator function. Nice, huh?

Answer (score 3):

I find the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7349731/how-to-generate-an-observable-from-a-starting-%20observable-when-i-can-only-generat/7356125#7356125) answer correct, but a little too complicated.
The only change I suggest is the mkInts method:

```
Func<int, Func<int, int>, IObservable<int>> mkInts = (i0, fn) =>
   {
      var s = new Subject<int>();
      s.ObserveOn(Scheduler.NewThread).Select(fn).Subscribe(s);
      s.OnNext(i0);
      return s;
   };
```

Answer (score 1):

I was not entirely sure if you meant to feed the eventual result of the function back into the function again or if you meant to have a separate function that would get the next input, so I made both.  The trick here is to let the `IScheduler` do the heavy lifting of the repeated calls.

```
public Func<T, IObservable<T>> Feedback<T>(Func<T, IObservable<T>> generator, 
                                           IScheduler scheduler)
{
    return seed =>
             Observable.Create((IObserver<T> observer) =>
                 scheduler.Schedule(seed,
                     (current, self) =>
                         generator(current).Subscribe(value => 
                            {
                                observer.OnNext(value);
                                self(value);
                            })));
}

public Func<T, IObservable<T>> GenerateAsync<T>(Func<T, IObservable<T>> generator,
                                                Func<T, T> seedTransform,
                                                IScheduler scheduler)
{
    return seed =>
             Observable.Create((IObserver<T> observer) =>
                 scheduler.Schedule(seed,
                     (current, self) =>
                         generator(current).Subscribe(value =>
                         {
                             observer.OnNext(value);
                             self(seedTransform(current));
                         })));
}
```

Comment: in the schedule call, shouldn't the argument order of the anonymous function be switched - `(self, current) => ...` instead of `(current, self) => ...`?

Comment: @Boris Using the 1.0 stable release of Rx, the compiler agrees with my order of arguments.  It is calling `IDisposable scheduler.Schedule(T, Action<T, Action<T>>)`.

Comment: Ah, I was looking at the [msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.concurrency.ischeduler(v=vs.103).aspx), which seems at the moment to be out of sync with the stable release. This also makes me not wonder so much about how you seemed to invoke  an `IScheduler` or a `TState` :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the code is not tail recursive and hence causes SO exception. Below is the code which works fine without any such exception.

```
public static IObservable<int> GetObs(int i)
{
   return Observable.Return(i).Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10));
}
public static IObservable<int> MakeInts(int start)
{
   return Observable.Generate(start, _ => true, i => i + 1, i => GetObs(i))
                .SelectMany(obs => obs);
}


using (MakeInts(1).Subscribe(Console.WriteLine))
{
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Or by modifying your code like:

```
Action<int, IObserver<int>> mkInt = (i,obs) =>
               Observable.Return(i)
              .Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10)).Subscribe<int>(ii => obs.OnNext(ii));

            // pre-assign my generator function, since the function calls itself recursively
            Func<int, IObservable<int>> mkInts = null;
            // my generator function
            mkInts = init =>
            {
                var s = new Subject<int>();
                var ret = s.Do(i => {
                    mkInt(i + 1, s);
                });
                mkInt(init, s);
                return ret;
            };

            using (mkInts(1).Subscribe(Console.WriteLine))
            {
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
```

Comment: Yes, I also think the problem is a non-tail-recursive Concat. I don't think your first solution is correct. What I want is for each value to be dependent on the previous value returned by GetObs. In your solution, the depended-upon values are already determined before running GetObs. Your second solution seems to work, though.

Comment: Actually, looking back over my question, it could be said that both your solutions work, but my question was not clear enough about what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, which, although it may not be the prettiest, does what I want it to. If anyone has a better solution, I will mark that as an answer.

```
Func<int, IObservable<int>> mkInt = ts =>
    Observable.Return(ts)
              .Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10));

Func<int, IObservable<int>> mkInts = init =>
{
    Subject<int> subject = new Subject<int>();
    IDisposable sub = null;
    Action<int> onNext = null;
    onNext = i =>
    {
        subject.OnNext(i);
        sub.Dispose();
        sub = mkInt(i + 1).Subscribe(onNext);
    };
    sub = mkInt(init).Subscribe(onNext);
    return subject;
};

using (mkInts(1).Subscribe(Console.WriteLine))
{
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: This solution does not actually terminate when you unsubscribe.  Due to the way you are chaining, the action keeps going when you dispose of the outer subscription.

Comment: @Gideon: Thanks, well spotted. I'm not even sure whether this could be solved by setting some sort of marker, telling whether to subscribe again, but fortunately, there are already some good answers, so I don't have to try to find out.